# Kryonet vs libgdx sockets

Tags: libgdx

I'm currently devoloping a MMO fast paced, with libgdx sockets(TCP), I recently read of Kryonet and how "fast" is it, from many users, people seems very satisfied.

Is communication server/client faster?

Do you guys recommend kryonet over libgdx sockets for fast paced games? If I use kryonet would I still have to do client side prediction ? or is that faster?

Comment: just looking at the github page for Kryonet they don't say anything about prediction, also it's more of a library than a framework (like libgdx) so it's unlikely to do more than just communication.

Comment: Indeed it is, sorry if you didnt understood my question,english is not my primary language. I only need kryonet for communication. What im trying to ask is if would be a faster communication. faster communication = less client side prediction

Comment: Im not trying to replace libgdx framework, my game will still use libgdx, im trying to replace the network communication

Comment: I've used Kryonet in 2 individual game projects in combination with Libgdx. Kryonet is faster provided you are decent at managing your netcode.